# Translation of a paper of John Tate

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, abelian-varieties, translation-request, mathematical-french

I'm just wondering if anyone knows if the paper "Classes d'isogenie des varietes abeliennes sur un corps fini" by John Tate has been translated into English. My French is not that good and I found it hard to try and translate it at the same time as I was trying to understand the math.

Edit: It would be best if I could get a translations of the whole paper but for my purposes right now it would suffice if anyone knew an English source for the proof that 2g = [L:Q] ([D:L])^{1/2}, where g is the genus, D is the endomorphism ring tensored with Q, the rationals, and L is the center of D.

Comment: If you mean the seminaire bourbaki paper, then should the exact same mathematics not been written in Honda's paper http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1260463295 ?

Comment: @Mastrel I think you'd have better luck finding an answer if you added more tags.  I'd add them but I don't speak French either so I don't know what the paper is about.

Comment: @WillieWong I am most interested in seeing the proof relating the genus of the abelian variety to the dimension of the endomorphism ring over the center. After a quick look through Honda's paper it doesn't appear he does a proof of this.

Comment: @Alex: the title in english is exactly the same title as that of Honda's paper that I linked to `:-)`. But I'll add a few tags.

Comment: @Mastrel: how about section 3 of http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=206004 ?

Comment: @WillieWong The paper I am interested in is a follow-up of that paper. It would suffice for my purposes if anyone knew an English source for the proof that 2g = [L:Q]([D:L])^{1/2}, where g is the genus, D is the endomorphism ring tensored with Q, the rationals, and L is the center of D.

Comment: @Mastrel: It would be great if you edit that last bit of information in your last comment into the question text itself.

Answer (score 4):

Learn French.

I do not mean this as a *cheeky* answer, but in all seriousness, if you are going to do research in Mathematics, learn enough French to be able to read math papers in French. There are lots of essential books and papers in French without translation.

Comment: I do intend to, and I do know some French but I found it difficult as of now to try and understand the math when I have to look up one word in every ten.